# Turn random string into ip address javascript

Tags: javascript

this may sound like kind of an odd question - but I would like to turn a random string in javascript into an IP address.  I am making a hacking game that uses google maps for getting places (so users can hack them), and instead of making a database with an ip stored for each place (which  would be impossible), I would like to use the pre-provided Google Maps place ID's and turn them into valid IP addresses, and then be able to transform these IP's back into the Google Maps place ID.  An example of a place ID would be:

`c66ae986ac80bff75c703418e757cf82b3cc7e86`

Currently I am using this

`const ip = place.id.charCodeAt(0) + '.' + place.id.charCodeAt(1) + '.' + place.id.charCodeAt(2) + '.' + place.id.charCodeAt(3);`

to transform the ID's into IP's, but it doesn't work backwards.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: And you want to create `IPv4` adres out of it ? or `IPv6`

Comment: There are 256^4 different IPv4 addresses, or 2^32. That hash amounts to 16^40, or 2^160 total combinations. There's no way you can go back from the IP to the hash.

Comment: Your code grabs only the first 4 characters of the string, so it would be impossible to regenerate the original string using the "IP" address.

Comment: You want it to work... backwards? Then you should keep a map of generated IPs to IDs--it's lossy; you throw away most of the info when you "convert" it into an IP. Plus you run the risk of collisions w/ the current conversion mechanism.

Comment: @MaciejKozieja Preferably IPv4; it would make it easier for players to handle/use IP's, etc.

Comment: You would have to fit 10 chars into 8bit number [0-255] this is just enough space for one :/

Comment: @DaveNewton I was thinking about that, but that would be a lot of data to store...

Comment: @cellman123 I was thinking about compresion but you cant reverse `abc` if you change it to for example `123` this must be sum so this might be `abc` or `bca` ... and its assuming length is always same

Comment: storing it or not is irrelevant; there is absolutely no way to create a one-to-one mapping between something with a space of `2^160` and something with a space of `2^32`. It's mathematically impossible. That means that even if you store each mapping, there are going to be situations where two different place IDs map to the same IP address, and then there will be no way to know, given the IP address, which place ID it originally came from. I suggest you come up with a new scheme.

Comment: @Hamms yeah I was afraid of that... I could just use place ID's directly and rely that the user is able to work with these more easily...  Hmm...

Comment: @cellman123 how about spliting it to multiple ips ? like using tracert to get 'route' of data?

Comment: @MaciejKozieja That could potentially work, I'm interested... the only thing then would be deciding which ip would be shown for which place, or if each place on the maps API could be 'hacked' using either of them...